# How connect control of winform using ip camera with opencv

Tags: c#, camera

I connect to camera, camera provide 1 control have name is: **AxLiveX1**.
I want using OpenCV(**getImage** function) to get data from **AxLiveX1** control contain **IpAddress** property to show information picture and convert it to text for check.
Thanks all.

Comment: I know OpenCV can access IP cameras using its URL with the help of VideoCapture. 
I try transmit: `Capture _capture = new Capture("rstp://example")` to AxLiveX1 control but can't success.

Comment: I don't know AxLiveX1 is library of SDK camera allows access to OpenCV to process data.